# reading data stream from usb bulk endpoint using libusb

Tags: usb, fpga, c++

I’m writing a program to read and write data to a usb device. Right now I don’t have the device so I’m using a loop board just to write the software. When I’ll get the actual device I will need to read a data stream, i.e. I don’t know how much data I will get (only the size of the packets), So I tried to simulate this scenario by using a while loop to write and read the data.

I’m writing the program on Visual Studio 2017 in C++ using libusb library.
My problem is that even when the buffer is empty (I stop writing) as seen in the example below (I stop sending packages when I reach counter == 3 but the program still tries to read) the program won’t terminate, it keeps waiting for input. I’ve tried using conditions like BytesRead == 0 (no bytes were read from the buffer) but it still won’t stop running and asking for input…

How can I exit this while loop when the buffer at the endpoint is empty? Or, alternatively, is there any efficient and easier way to read a data stream from bulk endpoint (preferably libusb functions)?
I’ve tried reading those posts:

- Libusb documentation for streaming – I didn’t understand how to read data from a stream, only how to write data stream [https://www.cs.unm.edu/~hjelmn/libusb_hotplug_api/group__asyncio.html](https://www.cs.unm.edu/%7Ehjelmn/libusb_hotplug_api/group__asyncio.html)
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-open-streams-in-a-usb-endpoint
- https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/usb/bulk-streams.txt
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650715/how-to-stream-data-from-a-usb-device-using-libusb-and-ruby-on-mac-osx

But they didn’t really help, I wasn’t able to implement what’s written there.
Here’s my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libusb.h"

constexpr auto VID = 0x04B4;
constexpr auto PID = 0x00F0;
constexpr auto OUT_ENDPOINT_ID = 1;
constexpr auto IN_ENDPOINT_ID = 1;

using namespace std;

struct libusb_device_descriptor DeviceDescriptor;
libusb_context* context = NULL; //a libusb session
libusb_device_handle* DeviceHandle = NULL; //a device handle


int main() {
    libusb_init(&context); //initialize a library session
    libusb_set_debug(context, 3); //set verbosity level to 3, as suggested in the documentation
    DeviceHandle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(context, VID, PID); //these are vendorID and productID for Cypress FX3 specific device

    unsigned char* DataOut = new unsigned char[4]; //data to write
    unsigned char* DataIn = new unsigned char[512]; //data to read
    DataOut[0] = 'a'; DataOut[1] = 'b'; DataOut[2] = 'c'; DataOut[3] = 'd'; //some dummy values
    int BytesWritten, BytesRead, counter = 0; //used to find out how many bytes were written/read

    if (libusb_kernel_driver_active(DeviceHandle, 0) == 1) { //find out if kernel driver is attached
        libusb_detach_kernel_driver(DeviceHandle, 0); //detach it
    }
    libusb_claim_interface(DeviceHandle, 0); //claim interface 0 (the first) of device (desired device FX3 has only 1)

    libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (OUT_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), DataOut, sizeof(DataOut), &BytesWritten, 0); // write data
    while (libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (IN_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), DataIn, sizeof(DataIn), &BytesRead, 0) == 0 && counter++ < 5) {

        cout << "Reading Successful! Data is: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < BytesRead; i++) {
            cout << DataIn[i];
        }
        cout << endl;

        if (counter < 3) {
            *DataOut = static_cast<char>(rand()); // generate random input
            libusb_bulk_transfer(DeviceHandle, (OUT_ENDPOINT_ID | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT), DataOut, sizeof(DataOut), &BytesWritten, 0); // write to device
        }
        
    }

    libusb_release_interface(DeviceHandle, 0); //release the claimed interface
    delete[] DataOut; //delete the allocated memory for data
    delete[] DataIn; //delete the allocated memory for data
    libusb_close(DeviceHandle); //close the device we opened
    libusb_exit(context); //needs to be called at the end 

    return 0;
}
```

CLARIFICATION: I don't want to read from number of ports simultaneously, I just want keep reading the same endpoint as new data is arriving to it serially.

Thank you.

Comment: Look into the timeout argument to the bulk read.  Terminate after so many timeouts or empty reads.

Comment: The concept "buffer at the endpoint is empty" does not exist in USB. And there is no concept for end of data stream either (except for unplugging the device). Additionally, bulk endpoints have no concept of messages or message boundaries. it sounds as if your missing something in your approach, e.g. a concept for sending a command to a device and then receiving a large result with some indication where the result starts and ends.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a PC programming question, not an electrical engineering question.

Comment: thanks everyone for your comments.
@chrisstratton I've tried setting timeout, but the program get's stuck.

Comment: @Codo I think I wasn't clear enough, the usb device is a board that is taking samples and saves them into a file. I want to keep reading the sample so I'll be able so save them. is there a way to do that?

Comment: @brhans I'm sorry if it's not the right forum, I'm still pretty new. since the program is to communicate with usb device, I thought that posting it here will be more reasonable than Stack Overflow.

Comment: "gets stuck" is not a valid explanation in software debugging.

Comment: Can you better explain when and for how long your device is taking samples? Is it a one-time process and then the device needs to be unplugged? Or does it take samples in bursts every minute? Or does it sample continuously? You seem to be expecting some sort of *end of stream* marker. But such a thing does not exist. Your issue is probably not with *libusb*. It rather looks as if you want to apply concepts of a TCP connections. That's not how USB works.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the terminal opens, and the message "Reading Successful! Data is:" is printed, and then the window stop responding and nothing is printed, I have to close it through the task manager

Comment: Thats not software debugging, that's a user report.  Usage problems are off topic.

Comment: @Codo It samples continuously. I think I'm starting to understand what you mean. I'll read about it some more, thank you for your explanation